# Reference existing control in scope of single function

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, sender

I may confusing with the terminology, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a move function which will end up moving selected items from one `listBox` to another. There are three list boxes with two right and left arrow buttons in between each to move the first list box items to the middle, the middle back to the first, etc.

My function accepts the different button names via `sender` and in the `switch` statement, I want to choose which `listBox` are the selected items going to be send from and where they will be sent to. If that makes sense.

The while loop at the bottom is going to perform the actual move, depending on what is set for the "to" and "from" `listBoxes`.

My question is how can I in the scope of this function reference the names of the three existing `listBoxes` in each of the cases of the `switch` statement? I know initializing a `new listBox` like I've done is wrong and will just create some more `listBoxes`. Maybe for this case the easiest thing is to explicitly put the `while` loop in each of the `case` statements, but for the future in a more complex scenario, I still would like to know how this is done.

```
private void move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button thisButton = sender as Button;
    ListBox to = new ListBox();
    ListBox from = new ListBox();

    switch (thisButton.Name)
    {
        case "queueToProgressButton":
            to.Name = "queueListBox";
            from.Name = "progressListBox";
            break;
        case "progressToQueueButton":                    
            to.Name = "queueListBox";
            from.Name = "progressListBox";
            break;
        case "progressToCompletedButton":                    
            to.Name = "queueListBox";
            from.Name = "progressListBox";
            break;
        case "completedToProgressButton":                    
            to.Name = "queueListBox";
            from.Name = "progressListBox";
            break;

    }
    while (from.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        to.Items.Add(from.SelectedItem);
        from.Items.Remove(from.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: What UI library are you using? WPF? Winforms? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using references to the existing list boxes, not allocating new ones. Also, your four branches of the `switch` are identical in the code you posted; I don't think that's what you intended. I made adjustments to the code based on what I think you meant to do in the `switch`.

Try something like this instead:

```
private void move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button thisButton = sender as Button;
    ListBox toListBox, fromListBox;

    switch (thisButton.Name)
    {
        case "queueToProgressButton":
            toListBox = progressListBox; // notice no "", but actual references
            fromListBox = queueListBox;
            break;
        case "progressToQueueButton":                    
            toListBox = queueListBox;
            fromListBox = progressListBox;
            break;
        case "progressToCompletedButton":                    
            toListBox = completedListBox;
            fromListBox = progressListBox;
            break;
        case "completedToProgressButton":                    
            toListBox = completedListBox;
            fromListBox = progressListBox;
            break;
        // Should add a default just in case neither 
        // toListBox or fromListBox is assigned here.
    }

    while (fromListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        toListBox.Items.Add(fromListBox.SelectedItem);
        fromListBox.Items.Remove(fromListBox.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```